# Unexpected JTAG ID 0x0ffffffe (expected 0x0202603f)

Tags: jtag, avr32

I have problem with upload program Flash for my AT33UC3A3256 Atmel. that what comes up when im trying to read JTAG ID:

> Unable to enter programming mode. The read device ID does not match
> the selected device or any other supported devices.
>
> Please verify device selection, interface settings, target power and
> connections to the target device. Timestamp:  2021-01-25 13:16:57.523
> Severity:     ERROR ComponentId:  20100 StatusCode:   131101 ModuleName:  TCF
> (TCF command: Device:startSession failed.)
>
> Unexpected JTAG ID 0x0ffffffe (expected 0x0202603f).

The JTAG pinout is 100% correct. I am using JTAGICE mkII. in .adtf file for my processor i have same

```
expected ID like this above:
 <property-group name="SIGNATURES">
          <property name="JTAGID" value="0x202603f"/>
        </property-group>
```

Somebody know what is happening?

Comment: is the device correctly powered?

Comment: Yeah, its correctly powered

Comment: There is no such chip, presumably you mean the AT3**2**UC3A3256.  AVR32 is a distinct architecture than AVR, this is definitely not an ATmega, and "Atmel" is meaningless as a tag.  Given the complexity of this part if it's not on an eval board with built-in JTAG, either circuit or JTAG probe connection mistakes should be the first suspect.

Comment: getting all ones which is what you are basically seeing means there was no answer, something is wrong either the jtag scan chains or the electrical interface

Comment: You need to provide far more information to get anything other than wild guesses in response

Answer (score 2):

There can be several different reasons why this is happening.

1. i dont know if JTAGICE mkII can power your device, but if it functions like Atmel ICE, you need to power your board from another source, (dont expect JTAGICE mkII to give it power)
2. Have you previously used this mcu/programmed it? You may have changed its settings like Oscillator selection to use an expernal oscillator and you done have one connected to it.
3. Based on 2), you may have bricked your mcu and need to use a new one.
4. you burned the mcu while soldering it.

If you could attach a picture of your schematic or pcb layout i might help you more

Comment: 1. Where I said that JTAG supply the board? My PCB board was developed by professionals and used to to programming seamlessly. With new order this issue came out.

Comment: 2. No, these are straight from pcb printing manufacturer.                                                                   3-4. I never has this kind of problem when board are ordered and this company making pcb's for years.

Comment: That this is a new batch of a previously proven design is key information left out of your question.  Sounds like an assembly error on this lot, or possibly wrong components (either mistakes or fakes).  Start comparing working and not working boards.  Inspect under high magnificent.  Possibly even swap parts between boards.